# Do I need to retain objects I receive in arguments?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management

If I have a method with input that is used do I have to retain?

```
- (void) exampleMethod: (NSString *)input {
    self.hey = [input retain];
}
```

What if I use `input` more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). If `hey` is a property with the `retain` or `copy` attributes set, then you do not need to invoke `-retain` on it (you can just do `self.hey = input`).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to retain a parameter that you only intend to use during the method. If you are going to keep a reference to it longer (as you seem to be in your example), then in most cases you should.

However, if you are using a property (which again you seem to be here), you should be managing the memory within the property setter itself, not calling retain explicitly when calling the setter.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the assignment to the .hey property a retain is implict in the accessor method.

[Accessor Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAccessorMethods.html)

If you want to continue using the string without using an accessor method, you may need to retain the string and the scope with which you need to have it available.